# web sql error "current version of the database and `oldVersion` argument do not match"

Tags: javascript, html, web-sql

I am trying to run these set of functions:

```
function erorr(e) {
  // error getting database
  alert(e.message);
}

window.onload = function() {
    prepareDatabase(erorr);
};

function prepareDatabase(error) {
  return openDatabase('tasks13', '', 'Offline task storage', 3*1024*1024, function (db) {
    db.changeVersion('', '1.0', function (t) {
      t.executeSql('CREATE TABLE tasks (id, detail,status)');
    }, error);
  });
}
```

But, after running this I get an error `current version of the database and 'oldVersion' argument do not match`.
Not sure what wrong I am doing here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ran into the same error.

I refrained from using db.changeVersion and used the following more imperative style of logic instead:

```
this.db = window.openDatabase('myDb', '1.0', 'a comment', 5*1024*1024);
if (this.db) {
    this.db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTable(...)',
            [],
            function(tx, rs) { },
            function(tx, err) { alert("Error in create table occurred: " + err) }
        );
    });
}
```

Hope it works for you as well.

/Fredrik

Answer (score 3):

Correct code:

```
function prepareDatabase(error) {
  return openDatabase('tasks13', '', 'Offline task storage', 3*1024*1024, function (db) {
    db.changeVersion(db.version, '1.0', function (t) {
      t.executeSql('CREATE TABLE tasks (id, detail,status)');
    }, error);
  });
}
```

While it's possible to open any available version of a WebSQL db (by passing an empty string as version identifier), you need to explicitly specify the current version of the db when calling `db.changeVersion`. The current version of the db is made available as `db.version`.

This is what the specification says:

> Check that the value of the first argument to the changeVersion() method exactly matches the database's actual version. If it does not, then the preflight operation fails.

From http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#asynchronous-database-api

Comment: `db.version` is an empty string when the db is created for the first time